# Just updated to Ubuntu 20.04, unable to send emails now using same email client I used on 19.10

Tags: email, thunderbird

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10 (did a clean install). I am using the same email client (thunderbird) as before but when I try to send an email I get this pop-up.

> An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:
>
> ```
> 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException`; 
> Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message WASCL
> UserAction verdict is not None.
> Actual verdict is HipNotify. 
> OutboundSpamException: WASCL
> UserAction verdict is not None.
> Actual verdict is HipNotify. 
> [Hostname=DM6PR12MB4434.namprd12.prod.outlook.com]
> ```
>
> Please check the message and try again.

Since at this present moment I don't have time or knowledge to troubleshoot the problem with thunderbird or the knowledge I installed evolution. after setting up my email account I tried to send the same email as with thunderbird, and it came back with the same pop-up message that I got in thunderbird. I figured since it happened in two different mail clients it may have something to do with Ubuntu 20.04 itself. Any suggestion gladly accepted.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the upgrade to 20.04 is the cause of this error. Is this outlook.com server your outgoing (SMTP) server, or is it some intermediary server?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to answer my own question, it seems that my new email address was not properly verified through microsoft. After ready my email that I received from them I verified my account and retried sending the email through "thunderbird" again, it worked perfectly. I guess I need to read my emails more often.
Jim C.